# Why do some Stackauth associated queries fail?

Tags: bug, status-completed, associated, stackauth

This query fails:

http://stackauth.com/0.8/users/137b94e5-050c-4dd5-82c1-aeb2af0814f5/associated

In Python for a `jason.loads` call, I get an error: 'ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")'.

I get this in the address bar when attempted using a browser:

http://stackauth.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/137b94e5-050c-4dd5-82c1-aeb2af0814f5/associated

But the [user](https://superuser.com/users/1931?tab=accounts#tab-top) has associated accounts. I see this with many users.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Where did you find this associated id?

Comment: @jjnguy: [/users](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=users) `users:associated_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed.

Site enumerations have changed alot behind the scenes in anticipation of [Area51 sourced sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/area-51-we-come-in-peace/), and stackauth happened to get broken for a little bit.